# How can a function accept an undeclared variable as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, function, object

I am working on a pre-boot camp problem set.  The following problem asks that we code a reply based on the number of times a customer has visited the restaurant.  An object contains the customer names and number of visits.  The function has 'customerName' parameter passed to it, yet customerName has not been declared.  I am confused as to why the object 'customerData' was not passed to the function, instead the actual keys 'names of the customers' are passed.  Code follows:

```
/*Write a function called "greetCustomer".
*
*Given a name, "greetCustomer" returns a greeting based on how many times that
*customer has visited the restaurant.  Please refer to the customerData object. 
*/

var customerData = {
  'Joe': {visits: 1 },
  'Carol': {visits: 2 },
  'Howard': {visits: 3, },
  'Carrie': {visits: 4 }
};

var greetCustomer = function(customerName) {
  for (var customer in customerData) {
    if (customer === customerName) {
        return 'Hello '+ customer + ', welcome back for visit #' + (customerData[customer].visits + 1) + '!';
    }
  }
  return undefined;
};

greetCustomer('Carrie');
```

Comment: when you call greetCustomer() the string you pass in defines customerName at runtime... You don't pass in the whole customerData object because this could be thousands of entries long. Just passing the current customer is a simple way to greet this customer. Obviously this is just a test question but it still applies.

Comment: `customerName` is a parameter - that is, a placeholder that will contain whatever is passed to the function when called. In this case, `'Carrie'`.

Comment: Parameters in the parameter list of a function declaration are equivalent to declared variables within the function body.

Comment: BTW the loop inside `greetCustomer` is totally useless. Just get rid of it and change the `if`'s test to `if(customerData.hasOwnProperty(customerName))`

Answer (score 0):

The `customerName` is a placeholder and is `'Carrie'` in this example. The value is passed in when the greetCustomer function is called. In other words, the whole function `var greetCustomer` , when defined, is saved in memory -- and that function knows that it may have a parameter `customerName` passed in. Based off where you are running this, you can even do a console.log(greetCustomer) to see the actual function and how it's saved.

To explain the entirety of what's happening:

1. The customerData object is saved in memory and will be passed by
   reference.
2. The greetCustomer function is saved in memory. Functions are also objects in JavaScript, so it will be passed by reference.
3. The greetCustomer function is called and passed the value 'Carrie'.
4. The value 'Carrie' is passed into the greetCustomer function saved in memory where it then cycles through each key in the
   customerData object using a `for..in` loop.
5. If that key (name) equals the passed in value for customerName then the function returns the greeting.
6. If the key (name) is not found in the customerData object, return no greeting, i.e., `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

A less verbose explanation would be:

Every time you call the function its parameters hold the value you passed or otherwise undefined

The other issue it's a matter of scope..when you declare customerData with var everything inside the nearest enclosing function (or global scope) can make reference to it.. it's good to know how to manipulate scope:

```
var // nearest enclosing function
let // nearest enclosing block
```

(none)// parent scope

I hope this helped